# SQL: SELECT rows with max date from created table

Tags: sql, union, maxdate

I´m wondering how to create a query that returns SERIALID, QTY, but only for the last INVOICEDATE.

To combine information from two tables I use UNION.

```
SELECT ab.SERIALID, ab.QTY, ab.INVOICEDATE
FROM (SELECT a.INVOICEDATE, a.SERIALID, a.QTY
      FROM SALESTRANS a
      UNION
      SELECT b.INVOICEDATE, b.SERIALID, b.QTY
      FROM SERVICETRANS b
     ) ab
```

I have two tables combined with UNION and my table looks:

[image: Table AB]

I would like to make a query that returns SERIALID, QTY, but only for the last INVOICEDDATE.

The result I would like to get:

[image: Result]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: You have first to GROUP BY ab.SERIALID and after add WHERE ab.INVOICEDATE  is equal to the MAX(ab.INVOICEDATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many databases support `LEAST()`/`GREATEST()`.  Perhaps the most efficient method assuming there are no duplicates is:

```
WITH i AS (
      SELECT sat.INVOICEDATE, sat.SERIALID, sat.QTY
      FROM SALESTRANS sat
      UNION ALL
      SELECT set.INVOICEDATE, set.SERIALID, set.QTY
      FROM SERVICETRANS sat
     )
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SERIALID ORDER BY INVOICEDATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM i
     ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note that if there are two invoices on the same date, this arbitrarily returns one of them.  Use `RANK()` if you want both.

Note that this uses `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  That does not seem useful for a query like this.

Depending on your database (and data), there are possibly alternative ways of expressing this query, some might have better performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS support `ROW_NUMBER()`, you can achieve this using `ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY` like following.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY SERIALID ORDER BY INVOICEDATE DESC
            ) RN
    FROM SERVICETRANS
    ) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Above query will return you 1 record for each `SERIALID` having max `INVOICEDATE`

Same can be done without `ROW_NUMBER()` like following.

```
SELECT *
FROM SERVICETRANS ST
WHERE INVOICEDATE = (
        SELECT MAX(INVOICEDATE)
        FROM SERVICETRANS STI
        WHERE STI.SERIALID = ST.SERIALID
        )
```

**Note**: Above query may return multiple rows for one `SERIALID` if the `MAX(INVOICEDATE)` is same for multiple records of same `SERIALID`.

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately, I can´t use this solution because I need to get unique SERIALID column.